# Вместо сохранения файла своя функция

Tags: javascript

Я пишу расширение для браузера, которое при сохранении  какого либо файла со страницы, если уже есть в папке такой файл, не спрашивает перезаписать и не записывает с добавлением (1), а выполняет нужную функцию.

Например:

1. правой кнопкой на картинке →
2. сохранить как →
3. в папке уже есть такая картинка, дальше должно быть окно, которое я хочу убрать →
4. заменить файл? ← , чтобы вместо него выполнялся код

Скажите, пожалуйста, можно ли так сделать?

Comment: попробуй посмотреть [chrome.downloads.download](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-download), стандартное поведение диалога, скорее всего нельзя изменить, однако можно добавить свой пункт в выпадающее меню

Comment: спасибо большое, так и думал, что придется добавить свой пункт((